# Event parameter with another parameter in JS

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have to catch the `event.target.value` in a handler. But my function takes another parameter along with `event` parameter. That's why it doesn't get the `event.target`. It returns `undefined`. So how can I find `event.target` if I have another parameter along with?

```js
function a(e, b) {
  console.log(e.target.value);
  return e.target.value + b;
}

var input = document.querySelector('#input');

input.addEventListener('click', function() {
  a(4);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<input id="input" type="submit" value="5">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `input.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  a(e, 4);
});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just accept it in the event listener, and pass it to your function:

```
input.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  a(e, 4);
});
```

With this code, the `return` in `a` is useless, though, since the value isn’t captured anywhere. You’d need to use that return value somehow, e.g. by logging it with `console.log(a(e, 4));`.

Comment: Come on this is a duplicate question! `(:`

Comment: @Ele The connection of this question to the dupe target isn’t _that_ clear to me, and likely even less so for the OP. The OP doesn’t need to add an `addEventListener` wrapper or something similar, as in the other question.

Comment: The OP only needs to understand how to get the event object and how to pass it to his/her own function.